# Adding multiple domains to objectProperty in Protege 5

Tags: semantic-web, owl, ontology, protege

I have created an ontology using Protege 5-beta-17. In my ontology I have some classes:

```
Mountain, Lake, Location etc...
```

I also have an object property:

```
hasLocation.
```

For this object property I have set the range the "Location" class, and the domain
the "Mountain" and "Lake" classes.

When I try to view the ontology using the CMap tool it shows that only the

```
"Mountain" "hasLocation" "Location".
```

The "Lake" class is presented without the "hasLocation" object property.

Did I do something wrong? Ore do I have do something else in Protege?

Comment: Did you have a look at the OWL/XML (or whatever you save it as) and checked if the two domains are there?

Comment: Yes I have seen the file. The domains where there.

Comment: But in Cmap just one of them appears.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found out what the problem was.

When adding a domain/range to object property in protege you have to click the following buttons and select one of your classes:

[image]

If you want to add another domain/range you simply click one of the buttons again and add another class. If you are doing it like this your telling Protege that the domain/range of your object property is an INTERSECTION of two classes. This means that the individual that will take the domains/ranges place is an INSTANCE OF BOTH CLASSES and NOT EXCLUSIVELY  OF ONE OF THEM.
This was my mistake. I was adding the classes to the domain in the wrong way.

So... The correct way for adding multiple distinct domains for an object property is the following:

Simply click the domain/range button again and select the "Class expression editor" tab:
[image]

And in the "Class expression editor" type in your classes like this: "ClassA or ClassB or ClassC or ...".

In my case it was "Mountain or Lake".

After that click "ok" and thats it.

Comment: This is the right way to accomplish what you're trying to do, but I'd quibble with the description.  If a property P has a a class D as a domain, then whenever we have an assertion P(x,y), we can infer that x is an instance of D.  If P has multiple domains, say D1 and D2, then from P(x,y) we can infer that x is both a D1 and is a D2.  That's what happens if P has multiple domains.  What you're actually trying to do is add a *single* domain that is a union class.  If P has the union class "(D1 or D2)" as a domain, then from P(x,y) we can infer that x is a "(D1 or D2)". That's a *single* domain.